# How to show columns from different table in TABLE FORM

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I've created List which gets Obiekt from database and i'm showing this List in select form.
Here is form code:

```
<select name="obiekt">
        <option selected value="default">Wybierz Obiekt</option>
        <%
            for (Obiekt obiekt : list) {
        %>
        <option value="<%=obiekt.idObiekt %>"><%=obiekt.nazwa%> <%=obiekt.adres %></option>
        <%
            }
        %>
</select>
```

In my database i've also Termin database which have following columns:
idTermin int, 
dzien Date, 
odKtorej varchar,
doKtorej varchar,
idObiekt int <- This is foreign key referencing to Obiekt table

Obiekt table:
idObiekt int,
nazwa varchar,
adres varchar

I want to make table which showing List of Termin (List), but I don't have any idea how to show Obiekt's name and address on this table.

Here is mysql code:

```
SELECT CONCAT( obiekty.nazwa, obiekty.adres ) AS Obiekt, dzien, odKtorej, doKtorej FROM termin INNER JOIN obiekty ON termin.idObiekt = obiekty.idObiekt;
```

And here is table form code:

```
<table>
    <%for (Termin termin : lista) {%>
    <tr>
    <td>THERE IS THE PLACE WHERE I WANT TO SHOW Obiekt.nazwa and Obiekt.adres</td>
    <td><%=termin.dzien %> </td>
    <td><%=termin.odKtorej %> </td>
    <td><%=termin.doKtorej %> </td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
```

Here is part of class where I make List:

```
while(rs.next())
        {
            Termin termin = new Termin();
            termin.setNazwaObiektu(rs.getString("obiekty.nazwa"));
            termin.setAdresObiektu(rs.getString("obiekty.adres"));
            termin.setDzien(rs.getDate("dzien"));
            termin.setOdKtorej(rs.getString("odKtorej"));
            termin.setDoKtorej(rs.getString("doKtorej"));
            terminy.add(termin);
        }
        return terminy;
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use mysql code as

```
SELECT obiekty.nazwa, obiekty.adres, dzien, odKtorej, doKtorej FROM termin INNER JOIN obiekty ON termin.idObiekt = obiekty.idObiekt;
```

for it to match the getString() in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Model should be:
idTermin int, 
dzien Date, 
odKtorej varchar,
doKtorej varchar,
obiekt Obiekt

so you can use *termin.obiekt.nazwa* and *termin.obiekt.adres*